# KDB: How to use KDB Function in Python?

Tags: python, function, kdb, pyq

I want to execute a KDB function within a Python Script. The KDB function is contained in a separate Q file though. So how can I read in this Q file and then query a function from within that Q file in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PyQ to call q into Python; a quick start guide is linked [here](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/pyq/)
. You can follow the instructions for installation and prompting q according to this link, then load in your script via the method shown in the example below.

Note: You should use the executable pyq rather than python to start.

```
$ pyq
>>> from pyq import q
>>> q()
q) \l /path/to/script.q
q) \
>>> x = q.f(arg1, arg2)
>>> x.show()
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, qPython might be an alternative... It allows you to connect/subscribe to a kdb server from within a python script, run q code, queries, etc...

https://pypi.org/project/qPython/